# How can i average a series of parallel lines into a single thick line?

Tags: python, canny-operator, houghlines

Im a student and im trying to do lane detection on an image using python language. Using Canny edge detection and Hough line transformation, i was succesful to detetct the lines in roads. But a single laneline is detected by many lines like this:

this is the image i tried laneline detection on
[image: this is the image i tried laneline detection on]

As in this image, the lanelines are detected,but in more than one number of lines. How can i average these lines to a single thick line on left,middle and right lanelines? Pls Help!

Comment: You may find the ridge filter operators of interest (Frangi or Meijering) - https://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/auto_examples/edges/plot_ridge_filter.html. Instead of detecting edges, they detect lines as you are looking to do. You'll have to tinker with the filter parameters to get it optimized.

Answer (score 0):

each line is detected by the equation:
y=mx+c
so you have to calculate the m,c so and use the average accumulator to detect all the ting liens into one line that has the m,c

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33664918)